# checking whether key value exist or not using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a key as

> "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{4CHJHSDJHSJHDJS-SDGSJAD}"

in my registry. using

```
Registry.GetValue("keyname", "valuename", "default value")
```

i can retrieve any value of it. But I need to check whether "{4CHJHSDJHSJHDJS-SDGSJAD}" exists in the registry or not. Can anybody suggest me what check I should use to do this?

Comment: Check the return value from `Registry.GetValue`, if it's not as expected, then it doesn't exist?

Comment: I am using Registry.GetValue currently. I can retrieve any value from this key value but not whether it exists or not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a registry value exists using C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276138/how-to-check-if-a-registry-value-exists-using-c)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With a registry key, you can try to get it with the `OpenSubKey` method. If the returned value is `null`, then the key does not exist. I'm talking about keys here, not values.

In your example, that would come down to:

```
var key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{4CHJHSDJHSJHDJS-SDGSJAD}");
if (key == null)
{
    // Key does not exist
}
else
{
    // Key exists
}
```

Comment: Yes I got it. Earlier I was having syntax error problem. Thanks all!!

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this

```
          using Microsoft.Win32;
          RegistryKey myregistry = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("MyKey");
          if (myregistry != null)
          {
           string Value=myregistry.GetValue("ID").ToString();
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can query for the Registry key with `Registry.CurrentUser` and then `OpenSubKey`.

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{4CHJHSDJHSJHDJS-SDGSJAD}");

if (key != null)
{
    // key exists
}
else
{
    // key does not exists
}
```